# Fit X rows to screen on Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently programming a little VBA code on an excel workbook to automatically show logs. So I have 2 sheets in my workbook. one of them shows the current logs, ordered by emergencies. The other one shows the new logs for the given department. The Workbook is connected to our Log Database and does a refresh of the data every 5 minutes via a View on the SQL database. My question is, currently, I did set the row Height to fit MY screen. I need to ensure the Row height is set dynamically to always show the same amount of rows. For example, if a user wants to be able to see 5 rows, I want him to be able to (via the form I created). I would then use a scroll for 5 rows. So here is my code:

```
'Check how many "Urgent" Logs are showing
Dim XRange As Range
  Set XRange = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)
  Set XRange = Range(Range("C1"), XRange)
  AnswerUrgent = Application.CountIf(XRange, "Urgent")

'Check how many "High" Logs are showing
Dim YRange As Range
  Set YRange = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)
  Set YRange = Range(Range("C1"), YRange)
  AnswerHigh = Application.CountIf(YRange, "High")

'Check how many logs to show
  TotalAns = AnswerUrgent + AnswerHigh

  For X = 1 To (Round(TotalAns / 4) + 1)
    If X > 1 Then
      ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=ScrollBy '(move down by 4 rows)
    End If

'Responsive sleep is to sleep and do events after each 250MS so the form will be
'accessible
' *4 to get 1 sec
    ResponsiveSleep (DelayInSec * 4)
  Next X
```

What I want to do is make this dynamic. If the user chooses 5 rows to display, I want to be able to show 5 of them and scroll by 5.

I do not want to scale for the whole sheet though. I mean i don't want to use the Zoom to get the whole sheet to fit on my screen.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a native way to modify the scroll for the bar in Excel itself, wouldn't help to make the scrollbar in the userform ?

Comment: The goal is to make the scrolling itself. It is a 'View only' screen that will display logs.

Comment: Is there a way to get the maximum displayable height? Either in absolute or pixel? This may help me find the total displayable rows (Height / Number of rows I want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to do this... I decided to find a way to go Full screen (Without title bar and everything) and so I could use the following:

```
Sub FormatWindow(ScrollBy)



    Dim Xres As Integer
    Dim Yres As Integer
    Dim MaxXPoint As Single
    Dim MaxYpoint As Single
    Dim RowHeightForFour As Integer



Xres = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
Yres = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)


'1 pixel = 0.75 Point
MaxXPoint = (Xres * 0.75)
MaxYpoint = (Yres * 0.75)

'Set the first row to 5% of screen
PointForFirstRow = ((MaxYpoint * 5) / 100)

'Get the rest of the space to display rows
MaxPointAfterFirstRow = MaxYpoint - ((MaxYpoint * 5) / 100)


'Set the first row to take 5% of the total displayable Y resolution
ActiveSheet.Rows(1).RowHeight = PointForFirstRow

'Get how many points per row
PointPerRow = MaxPointAfterFirstRow / ScrollBy

            Dim ws As Worksheet
            For Each ws In Worksheets

'If the sheet's name is not "Start", Apply the Height to all the rows.
            If Not (ws.Name = "Start") Then
            ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Rows.Count).RowHeight = PointPerRow
            End If

            Next ws

End Sub
```

Hope this helps somebody else!